# Is there a way for Svelte to load {#each} elements in a non-blocking fashion?

Tags: svelte

I have an array with 1000 objects representing data for a list. Right now, I'm doing this...

`Main.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import Item from './Item.svelte'
  const array = [item1, item2, ....] //array of 1000 objects
</script>

<ul>
  {#each array as item}
    <Item item={item} />
  {/each}
</ul>
```

`Item.svelte`

```html
<script>
  export let item = {}
</script>


<li>
  <h3>{item.title}</h3>
  <img src={item.src}/>
  <p>{item.description}</p>
</li>
```

However, the render time is noticeable. I was hoping I could do some sort of lazy loading with the items below the fold. I tried doing something like this...

`Main.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'
  import Item from './Item.svelte'
  const array = [item1, item2, ....] //array of 1000 objects
  const array1 = array.slice(0,10)
  const array2 = []

  onMount(()=>setTimeout( ()=>array2 = array.slice(10), 333) 
  //this will fill up array2 333ms after the component mounts, giving array1 a chance to
  //render quickly
  

</script>

<ul>
  {#each array1 as item}
    <Item item={item} />
  {/each}
  {#if array2.length > 0}
    {#each array1 as item}
      <Item item={item} />
    {/each}
  {/if}
</ul>
```

`Item.svelte`

```html
<script>
  export let item = {}
</script>


<li>
  <h3>{item.title}</h3>
  <img src={item.src}/>
  <p>{item.description}</p>
</li>
```

Which basically slices the first ten items into array1, allows array1 to render, then throws in a delay before array2 renders. This sort of works, because it looks like it renders quickly, but there is still a delay as array2 renders, so when I try to scroll, it feels sluggish.

It seems like {#each} is blocking the thread until everything is rendered, and I was hoping there's an easy way for {#each} to not block the thread.

Comment: I don't think you can change the behaviour of `{#each}` this way, but have you looked into something like [a virtual list](https://svelte.dev/repl/f78ddd84a1a540a9a40512df39ef751b?version=3.32.3)?

Comment: How about using Intersection Observer to detect that the user has scrolled, once the Intersection Observer is triggered you append more items to the list, i would also propose using a keyed each

Comment: @Tholle, I tried writing my own virtual list, but resizing the width caused all kinds of problems. The one you linked to looks like it will work a charm.

Comment: @OmG3r I thought about an Intersection Observer, but don't know how to append a Svelte component to an existing `ul` with out adding it to the array {#each} is iterating over, which I'm concerned will eventually lead to the array being so large it slows down on each rerender. But maybe Svelte doesn't rerender the whole thing, just the elements that were added.

Comment: keyed {#each} should only render the new items.